# Cmake ExternalProject_Add with PCRE library does not work with NMake Generator

Tags: c++, build, cmake, makefile, nmake

I am trying to build the [PCRE](http://pcre.org/original/doc/html/) library as part of a larger build. The setup I have works find on Ubuntu with CMake 3.2.2 with ninja or make, CMake 3.3.2 on windows with TDM-GCC using Mingw32-make or ninja, but fails when using NMake with the visual studio 2015 compiler. The build work on all these platforms before adding the code I describe below.

I used "ExternalProject_Add" to create a target for this build. Following is the section were I set some variables and setup the external project. I have removed several message statements for brevity. *LibFolder* is a folder in my source tree with and *ProjectBinaryDir* is out my output folder.

```
set(PcreSrcDir "${LibFolder}pcre-8.38/")
set(PcreLibDir "${ProjectBinaryDir}PCRE-prefix/src/PCRE-build/")

set(PcreCppLib "${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX}pcrecpp${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}")
#set(PcreLib "${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX}pcre${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}")
#set(PcrePosixLib "${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX}pcre${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}")
set(PcreLibs "${PcreLibDir}${PcreCppLib}")

set(PcreIncludeDirs "${PcreSrcDir}" "${PcreLibDir}")

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(
  PCRE
  SOURCE_DIR "${PcreSrcDir}"
  INSTALL_COMMAND ""
  BUILD_BYPRODUCTS "${PcreLibs}"
)
```

I use *PcreIncludeDirs* later to with the *include_directories* command and this appears to work I get no warnings or errors related to finding headers during any of the builds.

I use *PcreLibs* and the target name *PCRE* to set up the dependency between the PCRE library and the other libraries and executables in my built. Here is an example, *LibrarySource* is and an array of source files for the library in this example and *ProjectDynamicLib* is the name of the So/Dll being built:

```
add_library(${ProjectDynamicLib} SHARED "${LibrarySource}")
target_link_libraries(${ProjectDynamicLib} "${PcreLibs}")
add_dependencies(${ProjectDynamicLib} PCRE)
```

This works great with Make and Ninja again, but fails with NMake. The build compiles PCRE and most of my C++ code, then when it comes time to link to the it fails with the following error:

```
NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'PCRE-prefix\src\PCRE-build\pcrecpp.lib'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

At first I was concerned that the library name ommited the absolute PATH to my build directory. So I tried adjusting the name several ways including reversing all the slashes to make them more windows friendly and passing the library name as a relative path to *target_link_libraries*. I output every related variable so I could manually check them and I checked that the libraries were build and I found them in the folder they belonged windows explorer. I tried a few other silly things that didn't work.

Why does this break using NMake and msvc, but work Using Make, Ninja, Mingw32-make when using Mingw and GCC ?

Answer (score 0):

I was manually tinkering around with the PCRE build and discovered that it emits binaries with slightly different names during different builds. I looked in my output directories again and on my msvc builds I noticed that the PCRE static libraries had an extra "d" in the name. So they were "pcrecppd.lib", "pcred.lib" and "pcreposixd.lib".

I know that some build processes do this to allow debug and release builds to co-exist in the same build directory. So I check if this was a debug build by looking in the *CMakeCache.txt*

Working builds - line 17 to 20 of CMakeCache:

```
//Choose the type of build, options are: None(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS or
// CMAKE_C_FLAGS used) Debug Release RelWithDebInfo MinSizeRel.
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=RELEASE
```

Failing build - line 17 to 20 of CMakeCache:

```
//Choose the type of build, options are: None(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS or
// CMAKE_C_FLAGS used) Debug Release RelWithDebInfo MinSizeRel.
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=DEBUG
```

On the assumption this was my problem I decided to set the external project only to build in release mode. We can set it to debug manually in the unlikely event we need to debug the regex library. I used the CMAKE_ARGS as described on the [ExternalProject cmake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/module/ExternalProject.html) page.

```
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(
  PCRE
  SOURCE_DIR "${PcreSrcDir}"
  INSTALL_COMMAND ""
  BUILD_BYPRODUCTS "${PcreLibs}"
  *CMAKE_ARGS "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release"*
)
```

I deleted my whole build folder (to insure a clean state and avoid contamination with my manual tinkering) and reconfigured with cmake and rebuilt the software. This time it built and linked without error.

I still don't know why vs and nmake chose to build debug and the other toolchains defaulted to release, I also do not know how much of the "D" was the fault of PCRE, vs or nmake or CMake.

Comment: I will not mark my own answer as the answer for at least 24 hours because the community often comes up with something better than I do and I would rather choose an answer that explains why and not just what happened.